# InnerHits on document nested inside nested document while filtering on the nested document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping of following type:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "String",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "tags": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "String",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "tag_value": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "tagId": {
                "type": "String",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "label": {
                "type": "String",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The required output is to get innerHits of tag_value, but to only get documents of tag_value  of some specific tags.id.

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "id"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": [
              "021a9586-82de-4cbd-a651-e0b403d2b6da",
              "fee6e022-442d-419f-943f-ad2859013330"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "id": "xyz"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "tags.tag_value",
                      "query": {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            {
                              "terms": {
                                "tags.tag_value.tagId": [
                                  "english",
                                  "portugese"
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "inner_hits": {
                        "size": 4,
                        "_source": {
                          "includes": [
                            "tagId",
                            "label"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have already tried the above query but no innerHits are returned.
I have also tried to directly query the second level of nested documents but  then I am not able to filter hits according to id of first level nested document.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add `inner_hits` in your first nested query.

```
 {
    "nested": {
    "path": "tags",
    "inner_hits": {}, <-- here
    "query": {
        "bool": {
```

Comment: Still not getting inner_hits for second level nested documents.

Comment: you have hits, but no inner_hits its that's right? Could you add a sample of data to help us reproduce your case ? thx

Comment: H, I am getting innerHits for tags after applying your suggestion, but not for tag_values. I don't think I will be able to attach sample data.